# Python Serial stops reading

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project with a coin acceptor and a raspberry. I have the following code to test the output from the coin acceptor:

```
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 4800, 8, 'N', 1, timeout=None)
while True:
  line = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
  if len(line) > 0:
    print ord(line)
ser.close()
```

everything works fine and i get output from the acceptor every time i drop a coin. But after a while it stops reading. In windows with a serial port monitor it works and I get output every time.

Thanks!

Comment: try setting a timeout and re-opening the port from time to time?

Comment: ``ord(line)`` is going to fail if you ever read more than one character at a time...

Comment: You can use `.isOpen` to detect if the port closes and then re-open it if that happens.  Also, implement some debug logging to give you visibility into what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But even if I try ti print line directly it seems as it stops to read from the serial.

Answer (score 0):

now i have modified the code, but there is the same behaviour as at the beginning. After a certain time it stops reading:

```
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 4800, bytesize=8,     parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=1, timeout=0, rtscts=1)
sleep(3)
print("ready ..")
print(ser.isOpen())
while True:
  line = ser.read()
  if len(line) > 0:
    print ser.isOpen()
    print line
    print ser.isOpen()
ser.close()
```

the output from ser.isOpen is always TRUE

Comment: Figure anything out on this?